# Função que percorre for e vai excluindo conforme condição

Tags: angular, typescript

Tenho um array chamado listAtributos: any[] = []; e preciso remover as linhas que correspondam com meu index.

Se eu der um console log dessa forma, me mostra exatamente os elementos que deveriam ser excluidos:

```
removeAtributo(index: number){
       for(let i=0;i<this.listAtributos.length;i++){
          if(this.listAtributos[i].indexvariacaoatributo == index){
            console.log(this.listAtributos[i]) 
          }
      }
}
```

Porém quando eu troco para a função splice, apenas o primeiro elemento é excluido, tendo que clicar duas vezes no botão que chama essa função de exclusão.

Não deveria apagar os dois já que está em uma estrutura de repetição?

Com o splice:

```
removeAtributo(index:number){
       for(let i=0;i<this.listAtributos.length;i++){
          if(this.listAtributos[i].indexvariacaoatributo == index){
            this.listAtributos.splice(i,1)  
          }
     }
}
```

Exemplo de input:

Meu objeto listAtributos possui:

```
0: {indexvariacaoatributo: 0, id: 5, tipovariacao: "Cor", valorvariacao: "Azul"}
1: {indexvariacaoatributo: 0, id: 6, tipovariacao: "Cor", valorvariacao: "Amarelo"}
2: {indexvariacaoatributo: 1, id: 5, tipovariacao: "Cor", valorvariacao: "Azul"}
3: {indexvariacaoatributo: 1, id: 7, tipovariacao: "Tamanho", valorvariacao: "P"}
```

Eu preciso remover as linhas onde o indexvariacaoatributo por igual ao index passado na função removeAtributo()

Se o meu index passando no parâmetro for 1, deve-se remover:

```
2: {indexvariacaoatributo: 1, id: 5, tipovariacao: "Cor", valorvariacao: "Azul"}
3: {indexvariacaoatributo: 1, id: 7, tipovariacao: "Tamanho", valorvariacao: "P"}
```

Comment: Por favor, forneça um exemplo de input com o output esperado

Comment: dei uma alterada, veja se agora está dando pra entender melhor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que acontece é o seguinte. No exemplo dado seu array tem 4 itens.

Ao iniciar o for, ele vai tentar percorrer os 4 itens. No entanto, após ele remover o primeiro elemento que entra no seu critério (de índice 2), o último elemento de (índice 3) passa a ter índice 2, pois passa a ocupar o lugar do elemento removido e o seu array diminui de tamanho (vai de 4 elementos para 3).

Com isso, sua variável i vai para 3 e o tamanho do seu array também e o loop se encerra (devido a condição  `i < this.listAtributos.length`).

O ideal seria uma solução do tipo:

```
removeAtributo(index:number){
   for(let i=0;i<this.listAtributos.length;i++){
      if(this.listAtributos[i].indexvariacaoatributo == index){
        this.listAtributos.splice(i,1);
        i--; //evita que ele ignore o próximo elemento
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Vou testar amanhã e te dou um feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Como você está fazendo um FOR, alterando um atributo global, ao você buscar um item pelo index e utilizar o `splice` para remove-lo, o item seguinte do que você acabou de excluir, acaba ficando no lugar do item recém removido, exemplo:

```
1: { item 1 }
2: { item 2 }
3: { item 3 }
```

Ao remover o item 2, que tem `index 2`, o item 3 que tinha `index 3` passará a ocupar o lugar do item 2, então, terá o `index 2`.

```
1: { item 1 }
2: { item 3 }
```

Já que você está utilizando typescript no Angular, uma solução muito mais simples seria utilizar o método `filter`:

```
removeAtributo(index : number){
    this.listAtributos = this.listAtributos.filter(
     (atributos) => atributos.indexvariacaoatributo != index )
}
```

[Leia mais na Documentação Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro)